# I need a help about add to cart button for shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there any schema type for add to cart button & buy button?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work I don't really do html.

```
 <form action="/cart/add" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.id }}">
   <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
 </form>
```